# Create an instance of a given class

Tags: java, generics, gwt

In GWT, I have a a generic `Class<T>` in which I want to dynamically instantiate a `T` :

```
class MyGenericClass<T> {

  void foo(Class<T> clazz) {

    ...
    T t = GWT.create(clazz); //I want to instantiate T
  }

}
```

But I have the following compile error :

> Only class literals may be used as arguments to GWT.create()

So how do I instantiate this class?

In another thread I found :

```
GWT.create( Reflection.class ).instantiate( YourClass.class );
```

But I did not find a class called `Reflection` with this instantiate method.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes - you can accept, else leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java doc of create method says it all

> The argument to create(Class) must be a class literal because the
>   Production Mode compiler must be able to statically determine the
>   requested type at compile-time. This can be tricky because using a
>   Class variable may appear to work correctly in Development Mode.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#create(java.lang.Class)

In short you cannot dynamically create instance, the class type must be statically know at compile time.

```
GWT.create(YourClass.class)
```